# Shift + F10 not functioning the same as the right click context menu key on the keyboard (At least on the Task Bar)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, context-menu

When I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to access the taskbar and then I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> to get the right click context menu, it gives me this

[image] **Unwanted context menu shown above**

whereas what I expect if I press the context menu key on my keyboard

[image]
**The Context Menu key on the keyboard**

or a right click is this.

[image]
**Expected context menu shown above**

So how do I get the expected context menu if I don't have a <kbd>Context Menu</kbd> key on some other laptop or without a right click?

**Note :** I am right clicking on the google chrome icon and not the task bar and the goal is to open the context menu where the option to open an incognito tab is present and not access the taskbar context menu which would give me the options that would be present if I were to right click the icon in Windows Explorer.

**I am using the google chrome as an example, it happens on other icons as well.Eg: Word to open a new page or excel to open a new sheet(not shown in screenshot)**

I am looking for a universal solution that would work on any random windows 10 machine, so basically something that won’t require any third party applications and only inbuilt shortcuts can be used.

Comment: Win+T takes you to first icon on the taskbar. So it is giving you the correct context menu. Win+T is not the Start menu key. Ctrl+Esc, Esc, Shift+F10 OR Win+T, Shift+Tab, Shift+F10. Or via the System Notification area - Win+B, Tab, Tab, Tab, Shift+F10. NB: Only Ctrl+Esc to activate Start can be escaped - WinKey cannot be escaped.

Comment: @Mark I am afraid you aren’t clear of what I am asking. I have updated the question to make it clear.

Comment: What you get is the true context menu of the entry (accessible with Shift-RightClick by mouse), not the new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the screenshot you present, your application is at the 1st position in the taskbar.
**Its context menu can be then accessed by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.**

In general, corresponding keys **<kbd>1</kbd>**
<kbd>2</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>
<kbd>6</kbd>
<kbd>7</kbd>
<kbd>8</kbd>
<kbd>9</kbd>
<kbd>0</kbd> apply to the leftmost 10 apps currently present in the taskbar.

If your application is at position higher than 10, simply drag & drop it somewhere between the first 10 applications and the shortcut for its new position will start working immediately.

Source: [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

**Hint:** *pin* your favorite applications to the taskbar so they will keep their position constant so your keyboard shortcuts will always remain the same.

---

The universal solution regardless of app position is sending the context menu key (technically known as <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>) using some other key combination using [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com).
Example for sending it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>:

```
^F10::AppsKey
```

**Since keyboard input routines distinguish between the <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, you *cannot* force all applications by yourself to treat these two shortcuts in the same way** (if the authors of the application do not want to). You either need to contact their tech support to fix possible discrepancy or implement a key mapping on your own as I did show you above. Without 3rd-party app, you can [remap the key using Registry](https://www.google.com/search?q=remap%20keys%20using%20registry), but it is more difficult.

If you prefer keyboard shortcuts during most of your productive time, the AHK will soon become your life-long companion due to its practicality and endless possibilities. For example, you can limit the above mapping only to taskbar and not to other apps. Or you can extend the use of the <kbd>AppsKey</kbd> to be  another gateway to your favorite actions, e.g. <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>AppsKey</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> etc.

Comment: Thank You So Much for taking the time to type your answer but I just realized that I wanted a universal solution so won’t be using a third party application and needs to be an inbuilt shortcut.

Comment: @Valay_17 – For built-in shortcut, just use the first part of the answer. Is there anything else what can I add to the answer?

Comment: The Win + Alt + number works like a charm. I still don’t wish to use AHK but Thank You for the perfect solution.

Comment: @Valay_17 – Thank you for the feedback. No problem with the AHK, it is always only an option, not a must.

Comment: Mind if I ask how you found this solution? Maybe some great google-fu?

Comment: @Valay_17 – I added the link to the answer. Sometimes I read such articles to stay on top of current list of keyboard shortcuts (they always add some more). Some explanations in that list are not intuitive enough, but good thing is that understanding most of them is only a key press away. :)

Comment: I wasn’t aware of the fact that they continue to add shortcuts, thought it was only an update thing.

Comment: @Valay_17 – yes, after recent additions, large number of common combinations is taken, barely leaving something available. In need of system-wide shortcuts I retreated to Ctrl+Shift+Alt+letter (it is mostly unused, with exceptions) and to have greater range available, I opened AppsKey+letter and PrtScn+letter (it does the same, but on keyboards without the AppsKey). I also use app-dependent mappings, e.g. F2 in any browser bookmarks current page to my personal (browser-independent, cloud-based) library so I won't lose them again. :) Win+~ also opens Options in any app – much less thinking...

Comment: @Valay_17 Just wanted to point out that AHK is fully portable, i.e., your script can be compiled into an executable.  I personally carry USB drives on my key rings (and also have cloud redundancy, but that'd be for access from trusted devices), which essentially makes it universally accessible from any Windows OS station without installing any external applications.